# Change route if it starts with a certain string/character

Tags: cakephp

I have this in `routes.php`:

```
$builder
    ->connect( '/a/*', [ "controller" => "Api", "action" => "foo" ] )
    ->setHost("domain.world");
```

This works perfectly for URLs like this `https://domain.world/a/5nxdy9lmcthc`. I fail when I want to enable different routes depending on the first character(s) in the URL.

For example these different action targets:

- `a*` --> `aAction`
- `b*` --> `bdAction`
- `c*` --> `cbAction`
  ...

It works now with the `/` but for some reasons I would like to omit the `/` so the URL would be `https://domain.world/a5nxdy9lmcthc` or `https://domain.world/b5nxdy9lmcthc` and this would trigger different actions because of the `a` and `b` as first characters after the `/`.

**My question:**

Is it possible or is the slash needed in order to use to `*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greedy star (`*`) and the trailing star (`**`) are path segment operators, they will match the rest of the path segments, they do not match *parts* of a segment, so yes, a slash is required.

You can use regular expressions for custom route elements to achieve what you're looking for:

```php
$builder
    ->connect('/{key}', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'aAction'])
    ->setPatterns(['key' => 'a[a-z0-9]+'])
    ->setPass(['key'])
    ->setHost('domain.world');

$builder
    ->connect('/{key}', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'bAction'])
    ->setPatterns(['key' => 'b[a-z0-9]+'])
    ->setPass(['key'])
    ->setHost('domain.world');

$builder
    ->connect('/{key}', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'cAction'])
    ->setPatterns(['key' => 'c[a-z0-9]+'])
    ->setPass(['key'])
    ->setHost('domain.world');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes > Route Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, works like a charm, thank you one more time!